# converting str to YYYYmmdd format in python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have year, month and date in three columns, I am concatenating them to one column then trying to make this column to YYYY/mm/dd format as follows:

```
dfyz_m_d['dt'] =  '01'# to bring one date of each of the month
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'] =  dfyz_m_d['year'].map(str) + dfyz_m_d['mon'].map(str) + dfyz_m_d['dt'].map(str)
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek'] = pd.to_datetime(dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

but for both 1 ( jan) and 10 ( Oct) months I am getting only oct in final outcome (CalendarWeek comun doesn't have any Jan. Basically it is retaining all records but Jan month also it is formatting to Oct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `Jan` is single digit numerically, so you end up with something like `2021101` which will be interpreted as Oct instead of  Jan. Make sure your `mon` column is always converted to two digit months with leading zeros if needed using `.zfill(2)`:

```
dfyz_m_d['year'].astype(str) + dfyz_m_d['mon'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + dfyz_m_d['dt'].astype(str)
```

---

*zfill example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mon': [1,2,10]})

df.mon.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
0    01
1    02
2    10
Name: mon, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do

```
pd.to_datetime(df.mon,format='%m').dt.strftime('%m')
0    01
1    02
2    10
Name: mon, dtype: object
```

Also , if you name the column correctly , notice the name as year month and day

```
df['day'] =  '01'
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns={'mon':'month'})).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df
   year    mon  day         new
0  2020      1    1  01/01/2020
1  2020      1    1  01/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I like `str.pad` :)

```
dfyz_m_d['year'].astype(str) + dfyz_m_d['mon'].astype(str).str.pad(2, 'left', '0') + dfyz_m_d['dt'].astype(str)
```

It will pad zeros to the left to ensure that the length of the strings will be two. SO `1` becomes `01`, but `10` stays to be `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime) with your input dataframe. You may need to rename your columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3],
                   'dt': [4, 5]})
print(pd.to_datetime(df.rename(columns={"dt": "day"})))
```

Output

```
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/` between `year`, `mon` and `dt` and amend the format string to include it, as follows:

```
dfyz_m_d['dt'] = '01'
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'] =  dfyz_m_d['year'].astype(str) + '/' + dfyz_m_d['mon'].astype(str) + '/' + dfyz_m_d['dt'].astype(str)
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek'] = pd.to_datetime(dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
```

**Data Input**

```
   year  mon  dt
0  2021    1  01
1  2021    2  01
2  2021   10  01
3  2021   11  01
```

**Output**

```
   year  mon  dt CalendarWeek1 CalendarWeek
0  2021    1  01     2021/1/01   2021-01-01
1  2021    2  01     2021/2/01   2021-02-01
2  2021   10  01    2021/10/01   2021-10-01
3  2021   11  01    2021/11/01   2021-11-01
```

If you want the final output date format be `YYYY/mm/dd`,  you can further use `.dt.strftime` after `pd.to_datetime`, as follows:

```
dfyz_m_d['dt'] = '01'
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'] =  dfyz_m_d['year'].astype(str) + '/' + dfyz_m_d['mon'].astype(str) + '/' + dfyz_m_d['dt'].astype(str)
dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek'] = pd.to_datetime(dfyz_m_d['CalendarWeek1'], format='%Y/%m/%d').dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

**Output**

```
   year  mon  dt CalendarWeek1 CalendarWeek
0  2021    1  01     2021/1/01   2021/01/01
1  2021    2  01     2021/2/01   2021/02/01
2  2021   10  01    2021/10/01   2021/10/01
3  2021   11  01    2021/11/01   2021/11/01
```